# "First defined here" error in Eclipse with C

Tags: c, xml, eclipse, libxml2, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to compile a C program using libxml2 in Eclipse.  It seems like my code doesn't have problems, but there are errors when I build my project.

The error output is in this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwV-0_2diIaaQlZHM2Fwa2R0LWc/edit

Before this error, I had an “Undefined reference to” error, but it was because I forgot to link the library libxml2.  Now it's the problem in the screenshot.  I don't what to do.

[EDITED]
I solved my problem I just need to put `-nostartfiles` in the linker flags.

Comment: Any chance you can paste an example of one of those "First defined here" error messages directly, rather than an image?

Comment: I thought than paste the code will be a little messy but I will consider it for my next post. 
PD: I solved my problem I just need to put  -nostartfiles  in the Linker Flags :)

Comment: Pasting the code is the "normal way" around here. It can get a little messy, but if you can narrow it down to something decently sized, it's fine. The only things to avoid are a wall of code and/or code that you know is not related to the issue.

Comment: Nice job fixing your problem! Instead of adding "SOLVED" to the title, can you answer your own question and then accept the answer? That marks the question as resolved in the system and then makes it easier for people to read the answer later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem I just need to write -nostartfiles in the Linker Flags box :D
To find "Linker Flags" box go to Your Project > Properties > C/C++Build > Settings > GCC C Linker > Miscellaneous

That's it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your solution is acceptable, I think it will lead to the same problem when your project is executed in other environment (another eclipse configuration, running it from console, etc)
That error occurs when you have defined the same function more than one time in your project, and I bet it's because you have defined the same function you already had in a library.

For example, if I have lib1.h with a function called hello() and then write the same function in your main.c (having that library linked) that problem will occur.
In fact, in your image, I can see "multiple definition of __data_start"

So I think you just have to change the problematic function name and it will be fixed.

In addition, this problem will be caused if you include the same library more than once in your program, but it can be solved using preprocessor (if you are interested in this, google it, since it would be off-topic and make my answer too long)